# Derive $F(x) = x \, \sin x$ from first principles

Tags: derivatives, arithmetic, fractions

How do I find the 1st derivative $F(x) = x \, \sin x$ using the definition of a derivate? Here's what I've got so far:

> $\frac{dF}{dx}=\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{F(a+h) - F(a)}{h}$
>
> $\frac{P(a+h) - P(a)}{h}$ = $\frac{(a+h)(sin(a+h) - asin(a)}{h}$
>
> = $\frac{a(\sin(a+h)) + h(\sin(a+h)) - a\sin(a)}{h}$
>
> = $\frac{a(\sin(a+h) - \sin(a)) + h(\sin(a+h))}{h}$
>
> = $\frac{a(2\cos(\frac{2a+h}{2}) - \sin(\frac{h}{2}))}{h} + \frac{h(\sin(a+h))}{h}$
>
> = $\frac{a(2\cos(\frac{2a+h}{2}) - \sin(\frac{h}{2}))}{h} + \sin(a+h))$

I dont know where to go from here, how do I simplify to remove the $h$ in the denominator of the left fraction

Comment: See a proof of the product rule and follow that

Comment: is there any way to do it solely with arithmetic and manipulation?

Comment: you need to unwrap the trig functions, i.e. expand $\sin(a+b)$ in terms of a product of sine and cosine etc.

Comment: In your fourth line, you've basically reduced the problem to computing the derivative of $\sin$ at $a$ (and showing $\sin$ is continuous at $a$). How you show this depends on your definition of $\sin$. At its most elementary, $\sin$ is a geometric construct, and using that definition must require some geometric argument to match at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h} & = \frac{(x+h)[\sin x\cos h +\sin h\cos x]-x\sin x}{h}\\
& =\frac{\cos h -1}{h}x\sin x+\frac{\sin h}{h}x\cos x+\sin x\cos h+\sin h \cos x
\end{align*}
Now apply $\lim_{h\to 0}$ to both sides, remembering that $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin h}{h}=1$, and you should get your answer.

If you want to calculate $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos h-1}{h}$ just multiply the numerator and denominator by the conjugate, and remember the previous identity. Spoiler alert: The answer is $0$.